# Substitutions in Maple

Tags: maple, regular-expressions

Can any one tell me what am I doing wrong in the following expression in **Maple**?

```
subs(a*b*c=A, e*f/d=B, a*b*c*e*f/d)
```

I am getting the output $\frac{abcef}{d}$   and not $AB$

---

Update : after the suggestion of @String which wored just fine, I am now posting my real expression, because it seems that the algsubs gives an error.
The actual expression looks like:

```
algsub(b*((f/d)^t-1)/e = A, algsubs((m-1)*i*g*h*c*sqrt(2)*sqrt(1/(j*g))*s = B, a-(b*((f/d)^t-1)/e+(m-1)*i*g*h*c*sqrt(2)*sqrt(1/(j*g))*s*sqrt((2*(1-(b+a)/c))/a-(1-(b+a)/c)^2/a^2)/d)*e))
```

Which you can simply copy and past to Maple to get it properly. However, with the algsubs, I get the error `Error, (in algsubs) cannot compute degree of pattern in g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **algsubs** instead of **subs**. Unfortunately **algsubs** can only handle one substitution at the time so you will need a command like:

```
algsubs(e*f/d=B,algsubs(a*b*c=A,a*b*c*e*f/d))
```

for it to work.

---

### Update

Regarding your update it appears that **applyrule** does a better job and is easier to use anyway:

```
applyrule([b*((f/d)^t-1)/e = A, (m-1)... =B],a-(... and so on ...)*e)
```

Also, I stored the parts of the code in variables, namely

```
rule1:=b*((f/d)^t-1)/e = A
rule2:=(m-1) ... =B
expression:=a-(... and so on ...)*e
```

and then applied the command

```
applyrule([rule1,rule2],expression)
```

which worked just fine!

Comment: please check the question update

Comment: Thanks. You probably have to  correct the last command as you switched the command enteries.

Comment: @user2536125: Yes, they got interchanged. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use **simplify** *with side relations* (see ?simplify,siderels).

```
simplify(a*b*c*e*f/d, {a*b*c= A, e*f/d= B});
```

It is tricky to use **subs** when the left sides of the substitutions are more complicated than just single variables. For it to work the left sides must appear as syntactic subunits of the main expression.

For your more-complicated update to your original question, you need to first use **subs** to replace the syntactic subunits **(f/d)^t-1** and **sqrt(1/(j*g))** with single variables. Then use **simplify** with side relations.

```
simplify(
 subs(
      [(f/d)^t-1= C, sqrt(1/(j*g))= E], 
      a-(b*((f/d)^t-1)/e+(m-1)*i*g*h*c*sqrt(2)*sqrt(1/(j*g))*s*sqrt((2*(1-(b+a)/c))/a-(1-(b+a)/c)^2/a^2)/d)*e
 ),

 {b*C/e = A, (m-1)*i*g*h*c*sqrt(2)*E*s = B}
 );
```

Comment: @String: I was working on editting that code indentation when you got to it first. The indentation got messed up by the cut-and-paste.

Comment: OK, I hope you did not mind. I did not mean to interrupt your work! BTW can you tell the difference between the approaches, the one I gave and the one you gave? I mean **applyrule** versus **simplify/siderels**.

Comment: @String: The **simplify** with side relations is a very sophisticated algebraic method (see ?simplify/siderels). It uses Groebner bases. Thus it only works with polynomials, which is why I needed the preliminary substitutions. The **applyrule** is a great option when it works. I usually find it to be extremely finicky, but it worked easily in this case.